# Using the clipboard in FirefoxOS

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

Is it possible to access the clipboard in a Firefox OS app? If so, how? I know Internet Explorer has a way to do this using window.clipboarddata. However Firefox has never supported this. Do they use this method for Firefox OS or is there a different method or none at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not implemented yet, but it is planned for a future version. There is a [meta bug for copy & paste support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747798) in Firefox OS that you can follow to track progress. It seems that [Gecko already supports some Clipboard API events](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747798#c14), but there is no UI yet for copy-paste in Firefox OS.

Comment: Current nightly of Firefox OS has clipboard implemented. Just in case anyone is curious.